# How do I make my visual basic program wait for a button to be pressed?

Tags: vb.net, forms, button, input, wait

I'm struggling to figure out how to make my program wait for a button input. I'm currently coding an adaptive quiz for my A-Level project and have hit a brick wall.
I need my quiz to wait for an input from one of four buttons in a form. The code is in a separate module to the form, here's the code I have right now:

**In the form with the buttons:**

```
Public Class FormQuiz
    Private Sub Question_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles questionDialogueLabel.Click

    End Sub

    Public Sub Answer0Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Answer0Button.Click
        'Event triggers when button 0 is pressed
    End Sub

    Public Sub Answer1Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Answer1Button.Click
        'Event triggers when button 1 is pressed
    End Sub

    Public Sub Answer2Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Answer2Button.Click
        'Event triggers when button 2 is pressed
    End Sub

    Public Sub Answer3Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Answer3Button.Click
        'Event triggers when button 2 is pressed
    End Sub
End Class
```

**In the module where the quiz code is being ran:**

```
Public Sub runQuiz(selectedTopics As List(Of String))
        Dim quizQuestions As List(Of classQuizQuestion) = getQuizQuestions(selectedTopics)
        Dim totalScore As Integer = getTotalScore(quizQuestions)
        Dim userScore As Decimal = 0
        Dim buttons() As Object = {FormQuiz.Answer0Button, FormQuiz.Answer1Button, FormQuiz.Answer2Button, FormQuiz.Answer3Button}


        FormQuizOptions.Hide()
        FormQuiz.Show()

        For Each question In quizQuestions
            FormQuiz.questionDialogueLabel.Text = question.getText()
            FormQuiz.Answer0Button.Text = question.getAnswerPool()(0)
            FormQuiz.Answer1Button.Text = question.getAnswerPool()(1)
            FormQuiz.Answer2Button.Text = question.getAnswerPool()(2)
            FormQuiz.Answer3Button.Text = question.getAnswerPool()(3)

            'WAIT FOR ONE OF THESE BUTTONS TO BE PRESSED

            'Figure out whether the answer is correct, figure out score, etceter

        Next
    End Sub
```

I'm used to writing up console programs where I can just do Console.ReadLine() to wait, but here it seems there isn't an alternative with forms? I've also tried running a loop until a variable updates, but forms can't be used if the program is running (or so it seems).

I hope you guys can help me, this project is INCREDIBLY late due to personal issues - but if I don't get it done then I am practically done for haha

Cheers everyone

Comment: Use an object to store state. Maybe you are learning about Finite State Automata and can apply that to your code

Comment: The Windows programming model is that programs wait for messages, processes the message, then waits for the next one. All you do it handle the messages you want, called events in VB. So your code is attached to each button.

Comment: Please post an image of your form.

Comment: Have you looked into Addhandler?  Addhandler can be used to link button clicks to any subroutine you want.   Try something like: `AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Answer1Button.Click`

Comment: You need to rethink your solution from a console app to a winforms app. You don't usually wait for a button to be pressed, you do something when the button is pressed.